# Dearpygui status box not updating properly

Tags: python, user-interface

I am using dearpygui as an interface for a webscraping tool.  I have a "status box" which I want to use to communicate messages to the user.  It is setup as a read-only, multi-line input text box and is designed to update with the old value and append the new message. If I run the program, it will work but the updates to the status box do not show up until the webscraping(download_reports function) is finished.  The gui is not updating each time the update_status function is called.  What is the best way to get this to update and display when called and not when the entire process has finished?

```
def window_month_end_reports(sender, data):
    with window('Month End'):
        for building in buildings:
            add_checkbox(building)
        add_spacing()
        add_button("Done", callback=run_month_end_reports)
        add_spacing()
        add_separator()
        add_text("Select reports")
        for report in reports_list:
            add_checkbox(report)


def run_month_end_reports(sender, data):
    item_list = []
    building_list = []
    delete_item('Month End')
    for item in reports_list:  # LIST OF REPORTS SELECTED
        if get_value(item):
            item_list.append(item)
    for building in buildings:
        if get_value(building):
            building_list.append(building)
    update_status('Running month end reports')
    download_reports(building_list, item_list)


def update_status(message):
    set_value('##status box', get_value('##status box') + str(message) + '\n')

with window("Main Window"):
    add_button("Month End Reports", callback=window_month_end_reports)
    add_text("Status Box:")
    add_input_text("##status box", readonly=True, multiline=True, height=500)

start_dearpygui(primary_window="Main Window")
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the best way to solve this is to use an async task to complete the download reports function. You could use run_async_function to launch the download. You can find an example of the long task management in the documentation: [async functions](https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/wiki/Asynchronous-Functions)